# How to make my abbreviations work

Tags: vim

I have this in my .vimrc, which work correctly

```
iab abbash 
\#!bin/bash
\<CR>###############################################################################
\<CR>#
\<CR># File:
\<CR>#
\<CR># Date:
\<CR>#
\<CR># Description:
\<CR>#
\<CR># Syntax:
\<CR>#
\<CR># Author:
\<CR>#
\<CR># Copyright (c)
\<CR>#
\############################################################################
"
```

and I want to have this as well, but it doesn't work:

```
iab nyn 
\Indsæt dato 
\<CR>---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\<CR>Ny Note
\---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
"
```

It doesn't seem clear to me what the different is ??

What is wrong here ?

Comment: Have you ever thought about using some snippet plugin? Like UltiSnips or SnipMate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just tried putting them into a .vim file, sourced it, and ... they both work.

Try putting them into a separate .vim file and then sourcing it. Go from there ...